# Take all characters after separator symbol after 5th sign

Tags: c#, split, substring

I have the following:

```
string test = "200| Άρχισε ξανά| Start again| test | test? |201,202,203,204 |list | picture]"
```

How would I get all characters to the right of 5th "|" so **201,202,203,204 |list | picture**. The number of characters is always different.

How can this be done with c#?

I am trying with

```
line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf('|') -3)
```

but the result is "| picture" .
I also try to line.Split["|"] but also this is not working because I just want everything else after 5th "|".

Comment: This post shows no research or effort.

Comment: @dfundako What about now? I have updated the question

Comment: `...this is not working because I just want everything else after 5th "|"` You do know after the split you could glue the last 3 elements  together, right?

Comment: string[] data = test.Split(new char[] { '|' }).Skip(5).ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string test = "200| Άρχισε ξανά| Start again| test | test? |201,202,203,204 |list | picture]";

int pos = -1;

for ( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  pos = test.IndexOf('|', pos + 1);
  if ( pos == -1 )
    break;
}

string result = "";

if ( pos != -1 )
  result = test.Substring(pos + 1).Trim();

Console.WriteLine(result);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Or use the @RufusL linq version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Split` to split the string on the `'|'` character, then the `System.Linq` extension method `Skip` to skip the first `5` results, and finally `string.Join` to connect the remaining parts together again using the `'|'` character to join them:

```
string result = string.Join("|", test.Split('|').Skip(5));
```